# Is there a way to find out the compiler options that were used when a .so library was compiled on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, g++

I need to know how the library I have has been compiled, i.e. which compiler options were used? Specifically, whether it was compiled with optimization or not, and few other options.

Is there any way to extract this information on linux, x86_64 platform?

Comment: So given an existing .so file, you want to know how it was compiled?  Bear in mind that a library may have been generated from multiple source files, each of which might have been compiled with different options.

Comment: knowing options for each source file compilation would be much helpful..

Comment: Did you use `-frecord-gcc-switches` or `-grecord-gcc-switches`? Those options are there for a good reason.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe it's possible to automatically detect compiler options; at least not in a portable way.

What you could do instead is change your build scripts (e.g. your Makefile) to automatically append a define together with the optimization argument (the -D flag).

Answer (score 1):

If the library is coming from the Linux distribution you use, you can look at the source of the package, e.g. for Debian based systems: `apt-get source PACKAGENAME`, to get the build parameters.

Comment: Likewise, if it's from a RPM based distro, you can download the SRPM which may contain the build options.